# Error -lSDL2: No such file while using SDL2 lib

Tags: ubuntu, rust

I'm trying to write my little game project in Rust language, using SDL2 library.

I took the code from the "Getting Started" tutorial [from here](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2/index.html)  reworked it a bit for my project and tried to run it.
But got an error:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
 = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: could not compile `tetris` due to previous error
```

I tried to copy paste all the code from the tutorial without changes and got the same error.

Also i tried deleting Cargo.lock and the target folder and re-running the code. It didn't work.

And i tried to run my project in gitpod, but got same error.

So idk how to fix this error. Please help

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
IDE: VSCode 1.72.2
Rust 1.67.0-nightly

Answer (score 1):

I apologize to the community for my stupid question.

I found the sdl2 github page and read that i need to install libsdl2-dev before using the library.

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

So i solved the problem